# Number is printed as a negative value, but somehow tests as a positive one

Tags: c, printf

This is perhaps the strangest thing I have ever come across: A number which is simultaneously positive and negative! (And I can prove it to you, because I have the link to my code with outputs/inputs [here at ideaone](http://ideone.com/CuBmVR). Basically, my output is a negative number, but even stranger: when I check to see if it is less than zero, it is false (?!). Even more strange: when you multiply it by a number other than one, it switches back to being printed as a positive number.

This error does not happen when I compile on Xcode, but it does when compiled on the internet (or with some other compilers), such as the one in my link.

It's not important to understand exactly what it does, I'm wondering why this value is both negative and positive at the same time.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cmath>

int main()
{
    unsigned long answer,T,n,N,a,d,b,L1,amount;

    scanf("%ld",&T); // number of test cases to loop through
    while (T--) {
        scanf("%ld",&N); 

        amount = 0;
        answer = 0;
        n=N-N%2;
        for (a = 1; a <= n/2; a++) {
            d = N-a;
            L1 = a*d;          

            for (b = 1; b*b < L1 ; b++) {
                // "amount" is always a positive number
                amount = 2*(((L1-1)/b) - b + 1) - 1;

                if (d==a) answer+=amount;
                else answer+=2*amount;  // we are only adding positive values to this
            }
        }

        if (answer<0) printf("This answer is less than zero %ld\n",answer);
        if (answer>0) printf("This answer is greater than zero %ld\n",answer);
        printf("%ld\n",answer);
        printf("%ld\n",2*answer/2);
    }
}
```

Input:

`1
2500`

Output:

```
Success  time: 0.02 memory: 3300 signal:0
This answer is greater than zero -1842629629
-1842629629
304854019
```

As you can see, my negative answer is greater than zero. And not to mention, it's different from the answer when I compiled in Xcode, even in positive form.

I am amazed by this. It's printing out a negative number that is "positive"

[Proof is here at ideaone.com](http://ideone.com/CuBmVR)

Comment: Isn't this C++? Also, my guess is some type of overflow is happening.

Comment: It can be compiled in C++, but last time when I tagged c++, the tag was changed to C, because, well, there's nothing specifically c++ about it. I would guess some type of overflow is happening as well, but I wish I could know more of how this works. Maybe I should change the title of the question, but I still don't know exactly what is going on

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`answer` is unsigned long.  `%ld` is signed long in the format string.  Change `%ld` to `%lu` and you won't be changing an unsigned into a signed value at print time and it will print correctly.

```
    if (answer<0) printf("This answer is less than zero %lu\n",answer);
    if (answer>0) printf("This answer is greater than zero %lu\n",answer);
```

Comment: It seems to be working now... but the answer is still different from the one I got in Xcode.. let me check some things

Comment: `if (answer<0)` should be generating a compiler warning on most compilers that it would always be false, as well.

Comment: @user3400450 Nothing to check really. You should know that a big unsigned number will be printed as a negative number when treating it as a signed number

Comment: Well, it certainly is positive, but now I'm wondering why I get 36812076035 in Xcode, but 2452337667 in Ideaone (I copy and pasted the code, so they are identical)

Comment: I believe in XCode, unsigned long is 64 bits and in IdeaOne it is 32 bits, and you have an overflow condition.

Comment: @JohnH Thanks. Then, in order to prevent problems when using different compilers, how can we know or universally specify how many bits our integer is?

Comment: @user3400450 - include <stdint.h> and use uint32_t or uint64_t.

Answer (score 1):

The problem lies in the signing of your data types. You're using an 'unsigned long', which can't be negative, technically. Negative numbers can still be assigned to it and mathematical operations that lead to the negatives (such as 0 - 1) can still be performed. But the processor will always treat these values as positive.

I know that some compiliers will treat unsigned numbers differently depending on compile and link time flags and that is probably what's causing the difference between the two compilers. Or even possibly the website your using my be interpreting the code, for safety reasons.

Either way, change the declarations to just 'long' and problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

i can not add comment,but i executed in Ubuntu，and it show the same with you.
FYI,when i input a and 25,it's ok

```
myqiqiang@ubuntu:~$ ./test
1
2500
This answer is greater than zero -1842629629
-1842629629
304854019
myqiqiang@ubuntu:~$ ./test
1 25
This answer is greater than zero 12722
12722
12722
```